# How to make reference between tables

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner in MySQL.. Trying to do my first reference and cannot run it neither in MySQL workbench (Error 3730) nore on Live SQL from Orakle (missing right parenthesis). Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
CustNo CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
CustName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Adress varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Internal boolean NOT NULL,
Contact varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Phone INT(7) NOT NULL,
City varchar(10) NOT NULL,
State CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
Zip INT(6));

CREATE TABLE Facility(
FacNo CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FacName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FacilityPK PRIMARY KEY (FacNo) );

CREATE TABLE Location(
LocNo CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FacNo CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
LocName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT LocationFK FOREIGN KEY (FacNo) REFERENCES Facility (FacNo));
```

Comment: [MySQL demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb6c56888542d37eded9d7e181dd0c9b) and [Oracle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=795cd02f7e41c2d2d411525729e22ef8). Btw. phone/zipcode are not numbers(they contain digits but you won't do any calculation on these fields like SUM/AVG)

Comment: Which Create is causing trouble?

Comment: Note that although the individual components of a phone number are integers, their totality is not in any meaningful sense 'a number'. They are strings, and should be stored as such. Also, the number in parentheses following an integer data type is (almost) meaningless.

Comment: MYSQL and ORACLE are not the same or interchangeable. This code works fine in mysql but customer fails in oracle because oracle has no boolean data type nor can you qualify integers in this fashion int(n) (actually come to think of it oracle has number data type not int).